# Laravel phpunit multiple databases tests not running

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, multi-tenant, laravel-5.6

We have a multi-tenancy set up with one main and other tenant databases and having some problems running non-sqlite tests. Databases are mysql.

Currently trying to run tests against the main database and one tenant database. The connections in the model constructors are set like so:

BaseMainModel

`$this->connection = config('database.main');`

BaseTenantModel

`$this->connection = config('database.tenant');`

I observe the following:

Test are running fine with an sqlite in memory databse with the following settings in phpunit.xml:

```
<env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
<env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
<env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
<env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
<env name="APP_DEBUG" value="true"/>
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="testing"/>
<env name="DB_CONNECTION_TENANT" value="testing"/>
```

In `config.database.connections`

```
    'testing' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => ':memory:',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

However, when running without the sqlite in memory database (so commenting out my two phpunit lines for `<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="testing"/>` and `<env name="DB_CONNECTION_TENANT" value="testing"/>`) and running on my normal database, the tests start hanging after the first test.

So for example, if I have 5 tests in a file `SomeTests.php`, the first one completes, and the process hangs on the second one.

If I add the `protected $connectionsToTransact = ['main', 'tenant'];` to my `TestCase` class, even the first test doesn't complete.

Another thing to note is that I am overriding the `refreshTestDatabase()` method of the `RefreshDatabase` trait by creating my own trait and using laravel's trait. My trait looks like so:

```
trait RefreshDatabase
{
use BaseRefreshDatabase;

/**
 * Refresh the in-memory database.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function refreshInMemoryDatabase()
{
    $this->artisan('migrate');

    $path = 'database' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'migrations' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'tenants';

    Artisan::call('migrate', [
        '--database' => 'testing',
        '--path' => $path
    ]);

    $this->app[Kernel::class]->setArtisan(null);
}

/**
 * Refresh a conventional test database.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function refreshTestDatabase()
{
    if (!RefreshDatabaseState::$migrated) {

        $this->artisan('migrate:fresh');

        $path = 'database' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'migrations' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'tenants';

        $this->artisan('migrate:fresh', [
            '--path' => $path,
            '--database' => config('database.tenant')
        ]);

        $this->app[Kernel::class]->setArtisan(null);

        RefreshDatabaseState::$migrated = true;
    }

    $this->beginDatabaseTransaction();
}
}
```

I tried dumping in my test's `setUp` function:

```
class RelationsTest extends TestCase
{
use RefreshDatabase;

protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    dump("here");  // this is logged
    $this->product = factory(Product::class)->create();
    dump("product created"); // this is not. However I dumped in the model constructors and it did enter the Product constructor
    $this->someClass= factory(SomeClass::class)->create();
    $this->user = factory(User::class)->create();
    $this->otherClass = factory(OtherClass::class)->create();

    $this->yetAnotherClass= factory(YetAnotherClass::class)->create([
        'owner_id' => $this->user->id,
        'product_id' => $this->product->id,
        'someClass_id' => $this->someClass->id,
    ]);
}
```

Interestingly, if I run every test in the file separately, they run fine. So something happens in between the tests that I don't understand!

I have a feeling it has something to do with my model connections (or something). Because if I run two basic tests with just `assertTrue(true)` (not using factories or touching the database), they run fine.

Help is much appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Upgarding from php 7.1 to php 7.2 and adding this line

`protected $connectionsToTransact = ['tenant'];`

to my base test case seems to have fixed this partially and I can run a test class.

However, if I add the main connection, tests are not running

`protected $connectionsToTransact = ['main', 'tenant'];`

Also I am getting the error "Too many connections" if I run my entire test suite, even with only `protected $connectionsToTransact = ['tenant'];` . I assume it is because the `main` doesn't get disconnected after every test.